# Lazyloading plugin doesn't load images after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use lazy loading for hundreds of images on website. It is just working when the page load and it show the photos on first screen size. After i scroll down any image load to the page.

But when i change the browser size like 1px or more, it load images where the page size shows.
I'm using classic asp recordset to load images from database.

http://www.enfaltekstil.net/deneme.asp

The codes i use;

```
  <script src="jquery.lazyload.js?v=1.9.1"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(function() {
     $("img.lazy").lazyload();
     });
   </script>
```

and html

```
        <a>
          <img class="lazy" data-original="<%=Recordset("ImagePath")%>" width="210" height="228" alt="Collections"><br/>
        </a>
```

Thanks...

Comment: I solved the problem maybe somebody can meet with the same problem. The issue is the css code overflow-x:hidden; of html tag.

Comment: You probably want to do this a bit differently.  I am on a 32 GB Ram machine and still the lazy loading is painfully slow.  I am assuming doing lazyloading properly (like pinterest) requires you removing or hiding items which are not in the viewport.